# How to connect to file on same Tomcat server at server startup from within ServletContext

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I am trying to connect to a file(say index.jsp) on my tomcat server at server startup from within the context initializer method.
What is the best way to do this?

In essence I want to make an HttpConnection to a file on the same server when the server is starting up. Thanks!

Comment: No, you don't really want this :) What you really need to do when your application starts? What do you mean with "connect" to a file?

Comment: I want to get the server port number in a non-server specific manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no port defined for a servlet, so there's no place to query. Tomcat can have 26 HTTP connectors listening on 26 different TCP ports. You are trying to be smarter than the system by picking the port number from some HTTP request because HTTP requests of course have a destination port - however that's just that: the destination port used for that particular HTTP request, and it must be known **before** writing the HTTP request to the socket. Chicken and egg.

By the way, why do you need a port number? I mean, in a reverse-proxy deployment, for example, the port number is only used by the reverse proxy and should not be used to make hyperlinks, for example.

So, here are some advices: the Internet address of your application (protocol, hostname, port) is **deployment configuration** that cannot be guessed inside the application itself. Similarly, low level connection details like port numbers are **server configuration** that still can't be guessed inside the application and must be passed instead. These pieces of configuration are usually passed via:

- a table in the database
- a configuration file on the filesystem
- environment variables

The most recent trend is employing environment variables, that are used to pass configuration bits between programs written in many different languages and deployed in a variety of environments (virtual machines, containers)

Comment: So its not possible to connect to my server from within it at startup time? is that the summary? I really just want each Tomcat instance I run to log its listening port and its address into a database table for some other server apps so they can know which is online.

Comment: Well, everything is possible indeed, for example by accessing the Tomcat configuration, but you should not do it, especially while the very same application is booting! Some parts of the system may not be ready, some parts of the startup process may be parallelized... You don't want to do it. Use an environment variable instead

Comment: You see its dynamic..As instances of server A come online, they report in a database table. Instances of server B then check this table to know what instances of server A are online..so they can communicate with them. When or if they happen to go offline, they also unregister themselves from the table, so that instances of server B can stop communicating with them.

Comment: You don't need to make a request to your application to know the port: you start the application with a command like `java app.jar --port=9999`, just need `APP_PORT=9999 java app.jar --port=$PORT`

Comment: I really don't get that..I'm starting the server from within my development environment and the server ports have already been configured in server.xml..so?

Comment: For a vanilla Tomcat (no 3rd party configuartion framework) define system properties `-Dapp.port=9999` in your IDE (there must be a place in the "Run configuration" popup) and use Ant-style placeholders in your web.xml `${app.port}`

Comment: I understand your explanation perfectly... The server just runs on the system. It can have any number of means of receiving connections..thanks. I might have to rework the architecture, though I was able to get a server-specific way of getting all endpoints that the server might be listening on. I don't really follow your ideas as to introducing the port as parameters, but its clearer now.